# Show page number/same footer on the first page of a letter in KOMA scrlttr2?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering, scrlttr2

I use the KOMA script `scrlttr2` and just want to display the same text (my page numbering/number) on all pages of my letter, of course *including* the first one.

I've found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171774/98645) and [this somewhat old blog post](https://asktowolrd.com/tex-latex/scrlttr2-make-second-page-footer-match-first-page-footer/).
But both are awkwardly complicated and require me to define a heck of LaTex macros for just doing the same it automatically does beginning with page two (2).

How can I display the same text (page number) on the first page's footer as in the footer on the second/al other pages?
In contrast to all other questions I'm not searching for the most elegant solution (that takes 100 lines), but I'd be fine with duplicating/hardcoding the footer again by repeating it. Even if it would take me to write “Page 1 of \letterlastpage”.

I basically use this example, [taken from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578001/98645):

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}
    
  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}

  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout of the first letter page is special. The page style of the first letter page is `empty`. It uses special elements for the address, location, header, footer etc.

You have to use variable `firstfoot` to add content in the footer of the first page. If you redefine `\pagemark` to get »Page ... of ...«, then you can use `\centering\pagemark` for `firstfoot`:

```latex
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering\pagemark}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\centering\pagemark}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the footer on the fist page is lower than on the other pages. If it should be at the same position, then you can patch `\opening` to use page style `plain` on the first page:

```latex
\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer
```

or with package `xpatch`:

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer
```

Note that you can still use variable `firsthead` to define a header of the first letter page.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}
\opening{Dear Friend,}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know of an equivalent to firstfoot in the old standard latex letter class? Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK there is no equivalent to firstfoot in the standard class `letter`. But you can load a package like `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` to change page header and footer using `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle`.

Answer (score 1):

The footer on the first page of a letter is empty by default.

You will need to define your own first-page footer using the `firstfoot` variable and set its position from the top of the page with the `firstfootvpos` variable.

Switch the footer on with the `firstfoot=true` option.

The subsequent footers (done with `\cfoot` from the `scrlayer-scrpage` package in your code example; it works OK) can also be set within `scrlttr2` by using its `nextfoot` variable.

Also, since there is no letterhead in the example, and no reference, I've taken the liberty of moving the to-address and the letter body further up the page a bit, to use some of the space.

[image: first page footer]

[image: first page]

MWE

```
\documentclass[firstfoot=true,
enlargefirstpage=true,
firsthead=false,
]{scrlttr2}
%%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
%\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}

\setplength{toaddrvpos}{\footskip}
\setplength{refvpos}{3.5\footskip}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
%\markboth{}{}
\setplength{firstfootvpos}{\pageheight-1.5\footskip}\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\centering \textit{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}%
}%
}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{%
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
\centering \textit{Page \thepage\ of \letterlastpage}%
}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}
    
  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}

  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

By combining multiple answers (linked in the code), I've found a solution that just uses the internal `scrlttr2` parameter, i.e. mostly `\pagemark`.

Also you have one place to define the page number style there.

```latex
\documentclass[enlargefirstpage=true]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

% better page numbers with total number
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578072/98645
\renewcommand*\pagemark{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~of~\letterlastpage}%
  %\usekomafont{pagenumber}{-~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage~-}% different style example
}
% also show page number on first page
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578050/98645
\markboth{}{}
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
    \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
        \centering \pagemark%
    }%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}

  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\begin{letter}{%
    Jerry Garcia\\
    710 Ashbury St\\
    San Francisco\\
    CA 94117
    }
    \opening{Dear Friend,}

  \lipsum\lipsum    

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With package `scrlayer-scrpage`  page style `scrheadings` is used for pages 2 ff automatically. I would suggest to load this package with one of the options `manualmark` (manuell marks for the header) or `automark` (marks for the header will be set automatically). `\markboth{}{}` can be removed from the preamble.