# How to have an equal footer position in komascript?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

Is there a certain option have the next page's footer equally positioned as the first?

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%% \documentclass[firstfoot=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% Same left margin for everything
\makeatletter
\@setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}
\makeatother

%% Add a footer
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\centering foo | bar}}
\setkomavar{nextfoot}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

%% Move date to the left
\KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft}

%% \areaset{6.5in}{11in}

%% Don't use italics for the footer
\renewcommand*{\footfont}{\normalfont}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{addressee}

\opening{Dear XXX}
\lipsum[1-3]
\closing{Yours}
\end{letter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to load package `scrlayer-scrpage` which is part of the KOMA-Script bundle.

If the footer on the second page should be at the same height as the first:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% Same left margin for everything
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}

%% Add a footer
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\parbox[b]{\useplength{firstfootwidth}}{\centering foo | bar}}

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\KOMAoptions{footwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}{%
    \ModifyLayer[
      voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos}
    ]{#1}
  }{}%
}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont}

%% Move date to the left
\KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{addressee}
\opening{Dear XXX}
\lipsum[1-3]
\closing{Yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the footer on the first page should be at the same height as on other pages (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578081):

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%% Same left margin for everything
\setplength{toaddrhpos}{\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in}


%% Add a footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\cfoot*{foo | bar}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\normalfont}

\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}
\KOMAoptions{firstfoot=false}% disable first footer

%% Move date to the left
\KOMAoptions{refline=dateleft}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{addressee}
\opening{Dear XXX}
\lipsum[1-3]
\closing{Yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]