# How do I force the pagemark footer to be shown on all pages, including the first?

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, scrlttr2, footer

I'm trying to create a letter template and want every page to show the current page and the total number of pages. However, I cannot get koma script to display the custom `\pagemark` on the first page. It always starts on the second. At the same time, the header is to be shown *only* at the second page as the first page has a custom header.

*MRE*

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}
\KOMAoption{firsthead}{yes}
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{yes}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{\Ifkomavarempty{subject}{}{\centering\usekomavar{subject}}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{{\usekomafont{pagenumber}custom~pg~\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{sender}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{Custom firsthead}
% the following workaround doesn't work as intended
% because the bottom spacing of the 'firstfoot' is
% different from the regular footer distance
%%\setkomavar{firstfoot}{%
%%\centering\pagemark%
%%}
\setkomavar{date}{Date}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

\begin{letter}{Addressee}
\opening{Hello}
World
\Blindtext
\closing{Cheers}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The custom pagemark is shown on the second page but not the first:

[image: rendered document]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `\thispagestyle{plain}` after `\opening{...}` to change the page style of the first page from `empty` to `plain`:

```latex
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{no}% <- changed: disable firstfoot
...
\opening{Hello}
\thispagestyle{plain}% <- added
```

Note that you have to disable `firstfoot`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578081/43317.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}% default
%\KOMAoption{firsthead}{yes}% default
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{no}% <- changed: disable firstfoot
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\usekomavar{subject}}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{custom~pg~\thepage}}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{sender}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{Custom firsthead}
\setkomavar{date}{Date}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

\begin{letter}{Addressee}
\opening{Hello}
\thispagestyle{plain}% <- added

World
\Blindtext
\closing{Cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also patch `\opening` using

```latex
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{no}% <- changed: disable firstfoot
...
\newcommand{\originalopening}{}
\let\originalopening\opening
\renewcommand{\opening}[1]{\originalopening{#1}\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

or

```latex
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{no}% <- changed: disable firstfoot
...
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}
```

in the preamble.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%\KOMAoption{paper}{a4}% default
%\KOMAoption{firsthead}{yes}% default
\KOMAoption{firstfoot}{no}% <- changed: disable firstfoot
\usepackage{blindtext}

\pagestyle{myheadings}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\centering\usekomavar{subject}}}
\renewcommand\pagemark{\usekomafont{pagenumber}{custom~pg~\thepage}}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\opening}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{sender}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{address}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{Custom firsthead}
\setkomavar{date}{Date}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

\begin{letter}{Addressee}
\opening{Hello}
World
\Blindtext
\closing{Cheers}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Yes, `xpatchcmd` was the command I didn't know I needed all my life. Marvellous!